# selecting last inserted row in mysql and other conditions

Tags: php, mysql

### im having the table name fiscalyear

---

These are the columns

- id(auto increment)
- begin (financial year begin date)
- end    (financial year end date)
- active (either 0(open) or 1(closed))
- begin column consists dates like 2012-01-01
- end column consists dates like 2013-12-31

i want to get the financial year begin and end date

### These are the conditions

1. which is open i.e 0,
2. also it should be the last inserted.

### Here is the query i tried please update my query according to my conditions

```
SELECT CONCAT(BEGIN,'/',END) AS YEAR FROM fiscalyear WHERE active='0' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1
```

---

THE ABOVE QUERY SELECT DATE IN THIS FORMAT: 2012-01-01/2013-12-31 BUT INSTEAD OF THIS I WANT TO PRINT THE SELETED DATE IN THIS FORMAT 2012-13..

Answer (score 2):

If you want the last row, you can order the table in DESC order by `id` which is auto increment.

```
SELECT `BEGIN`,`END` 
FROM `fiscalyear` 
WHERE `active`='0' 
ORDER BY `id` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

It should be noted that BEGIN and END are reserved words in MySQL, and should be represented as fields using "`"

As for printing the date, I recommend PHP class [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Comment: the thing is that we should have to concat both the begin and end column... and it should print on the screen in this format 2012-13 (where 2012 is the begin year and 13 is the end year)

Answer (score 0):

Order it by the `id` primary key, and use a `LIMIT 1`, so you only get the last record. Use the built in `DATE_FORMAT` to format your date.

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(`BEGIN`, '%Y'), '-',
    DATE_FORMAT(`END`, '%Y')) AS mydates
FROM
    `fiscalyear`
WHERE
    `active` = 0
ORDER BY
    `id` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Edit: I changed the query to concat the years so it will output `2012-2013`. The result will be in `mydates`. If you want the end year to be `13` instead of `2013` format, then use `%y` a lowercase `y` in the format string.

Comment: the thing is that we should have to concat both the begin and end column... and it should print on the screen in this format 2012-13  (where 2012 is the begin year and 13 is the end year)

Comment: @jax I edited the answer to do the concat, it will give you the years concatenated and formated.

Comment: but instead of placing Y in the second field place y.. it selects last two digits @mr code

Comment: Use uppercase Y for 2013. Use lowercase y for 13. If this solved your problem please accept the answer by clicking the tick

Answer (score 0):

About your second question, you can define Begin and End in your database as DateTime (i remember some data type like this was defined in mySQL) and then you can use this function:

```
/* Analyzes time-date and returns mktime!*/
function analyze_time_date($tdstr)
{
    // tdstr : 2010-08-12 11:41:14
    //         0000000000111111111
    //         0123456789012345678
    $year   = (int)substr($tdstr,0,4);
    $month  = (int)substr($tdstr,5,2);
    $day    = (int)substr($tdstr,8,2);

    $hour   = (int)substr($tdstr,11,2);
    $minute = (int)substr($tdstr,14,2);
    $second = (int)substr($tdstr,17,2);

    return mktime($hour,$minute,$second,$month,$day,$year);
}

/*  */
function format_time_date($tdstr,$format)
{
        return date($format,analyze_time_date($tdstr));
}
```

when you wanna insert a new row to your database you should use `'date time field name' = NOW()` in your SQL query.

Comment: the thing is that we should have to concat both the begin and end column... and it should print on the screen in this format 2012-13 (where 2012 is the begin year and 13 is the end year)

Comment: `echo date("Y", ana...ate($begin)). "-" . date("y", ana...ate($end));`
http://ir2.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

### Here is the query what i need

```
SELECT
CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(`BEGIN`, '%Y'), '-',
DATE_FORMAT(`END`, '%y')) AS mydates
```

FROM
    `0_fiscal_year`
WHERE
    `closed` = 0
ORDER BY
    `id` DESC
LIMIT 1